# Sporadic Angular2 error when running angular.io Hero Editor tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error occasionally in console as I am following the angular.io tutorial. I am using Mozilla Firefox. It does not happen very often and doesn't appear to hinder the logic/rendering of my application.

Please let me know what information to provide to diagnose this problem. Refreshing the page without any changes to the application results in it being loaded without this error present.

```
23:04:04.794 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:23
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:28
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:28

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js as "./util/isFunction" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js
Stack trace:
(SystemJS) XHR error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:23
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:28
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:28

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js as "./util/isFunction" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js1localhost:3000:16:51
<anonymous>localhost:3000:16
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke()zone.js:203
Zone.prototype.run()zone.js:96
scheduleResolveOrReject/<()zone.js:462
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask()zone.js:236
Zone.prototype.runTask()zone.js:136
drainMicroTaskQueue()zone.js:368
ZoneTask/this.invoke()zone.js:308
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error is sporadic, it may have to do with the server, not the application. Meaning, if you're running `lite-server` or some other utility that serves your files to the browser and watches for changes, that may be generating errors.

Comment: sounds plausible. I suppose if the lite-server is loading the files (after detecting a change in a typescript file, perhaps while it transpiling) it may be somehow being unable to load the transpiled javascript file? Just guessing here as I am very new to this